# Python how to apply per-column mean on Series of series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, series

I have a series with 800 elements.
Each element - is a series with n elementes , `800 < n <= 1200`, so the longest series `len` is 1200.
I want to have a single vector with 1200 elements, each element value - is the mean of this position for all series.
So if:

```
s = ([1,2,3,4,5,6,1],
     [1,3,9,6],
     [4,4])
```

I will get:

```
v = [2,3,6,5,5,6,1]
```

What will be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Create `DataFrame` by constructor and use `mean`:

```
s = pd.Series(([1,2,3,4,5,6,1],
               [1,3,9,6],
               [4,4]))

out = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist()).mean().tolist()
print (out)
[2.0, 3.0, 6.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 1.0]
```